# How to use pickle.load in flask app - Python3

Tags: flask, python-3.6, pickle, pem

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == 'POST':

    if 'files[]' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)

    files = request.files.getlist('files[]')

    for file in files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            #print(file.filename)
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            encrypted_list = pickle.load(open(file, "rb"))
            print(encrypted_list)
```

I am having some string whose base64 encoding I have stored in .pem files and idea is **X** person will upload multiple .pem files in the flask app and I don't want to save them in disk, just read those .pem files using **pickle.load(open(file, "rb"))** but this command is giving me error. As while encrypting I have stored those base64 encoded string in .pem files. Now I want to decode those string from .pem files in Flask.

Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to show us the error message.

Comment: encrypted_list = pickle.load(open(file, "rb"))
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you cannot pass a `FileStorage` instance into pickle's load function.

Instead, you should pass in a file like object, like so `encrypted_list = pickle.load(file.stream)`.

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage